# VSTS Build: .NETFramework v4.6 assemblies not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've got a couple builds in my VSTS build pipeline. A pull request build that builds the solution, the 'Build Solution' step works fine here, everything completes. Then it goes into a CI_Build, then it goes into a CI_Build and this builds the solution to be deployed through Octopus. The CI_Build seems to be set up the same way as the first build, yet I get the following error:

Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Anyone know what could cause a successful 'Build Solution' in one build, but not another when it's building the same solution?

Comment: Check to make sure that your build is using the "Hosted VS2017" build agent pool.

Comment: That was it, but slightly different. We've got some private agent pools set up and I was using the wrong one. Thank you very much for leading me there!

Comment: @TomBrothers please provide your comment as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got some private agent pools set up and I was using the wrong one. The agent pool must include VS2017